# How to communicate between two different application in android through aidl and IPC?

Tags: android

i want to establish communication in some different application. all application has been developed by me only. so is it possible to use AIDL and IPC for same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very good tutorial for creating a [background service by using AIDL](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/37/android-architecture-tutorial-developing-an-app-with-a-background-service-using-ipc/). 
What you can do is put your AIDL files in service app and develop your service features. Then copy those AIDL files without service implementation to other application. Now, the second app can make connection to your service (which is deployed by other application).

Comment: Thanks Amir i got solution ... :)